# How to Fetch Contacts from iCloud to an application?

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-api

I need my application to load or fetch all contacts from my iCloud account. 'CNContactStore' allows only to fetch contacts from my device. Is Apple providing any API's or is there any SDK's that are available. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Your best bet would be to use the CardDAV standard that is supported by Apple as detailed in this [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912365/399435).

Answer (score 0):

There is API provided by Apple to access iCloud: [iCloud-API](https://github.com/mindcollapse/iCloud-API)

Please refer above link to know more in detail. Let me know if you have a query in understanding.

Comment: The link suggests that It can't be used for any production purposes. Apple will reject this API.

Comment: Is there any documentation that Apple intentionally said that?

Comment: Refer this below link for more info: https://www.programmableweb.com/api/apple-icloud

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I am not able to find a proper solution to implement that in either Objective-c or swift language.